# Ansible playbook failing to find custom module

Tags: python, python-2.7, ansible, ansible-2.x

I have a module called "mysync" which is a small modification of synchronize. Bottom of this ticket is a diff between syncronize and mysync. It is placed it in the library directory:

```
library        = /sites/utils/local/ansible/modules
```

when running the module in a playbook, the module is not found. Recommendations?

```
@> cat play.yml

- hosts: all
  name: put shop onto server
  mysync:
        mode: pull
        module: shop
        src: rsync://@DEPOTHOST@::shop.ear
        dest: /sites/MODULES/
        archive: no
        compress: yes
        copy_links: yes
        delete: yes
        links: yes
        times: yes
        use_ssh_args: yes
        verify_host: no
        delegate_to: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"

@>ansible-playbook ./sync_shop.yml --limit tst37 -vvv
ERROR! 'mysync' is not a valid attribute for a Play

The error appears to have been in '/sites/utils/local/ansible/modules/sync_shop.yml': line 1, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


- hosts: all
  ^ here



@>diff diff /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/files/synchronize.py ./mysync.py

26,28c26,28
< module: synchronize
< version_added: "1.4"
< short_description: A wrapper around rsync to make common tasks in your playbooks quick and easy.
---
> module: mySync
> version_added: "2.1"
> short_description: A custom wrapper around rsync to get src-host, src and dest from ldap

302a303,304
> import socket
> from ansible.module_utils.ldapData import ldapData
370a373,382
>     #myInv = ldapData(self.args.debug,self.args.file,self.args.refresh)
>     myInv = ldapData()
>     host = socket.getfqdn()
>     mydata = hosts[host][instances]
>     for inst in mydata:
>   if 'depothost' in inst:
>       src_host=inst['depothost']
>     if src_host is None:
>   module.fail_json(msg='Could not determine depothost')
> 
378a391
>   source.replace('@DEPOTHOST@',src_host)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not "call" modules (custom or standard) directly from a play.

You should add them to a `tasks` dictionary which is missing in your play.

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: put shop onto server
      mysync: 
        mode: pull
        module: shop
        # etc.
```